# Unable to get url value from json cell

Tags: php, arrays, json, file-get-contents

I have an api that returns a json where I want to get some data. When I visit the url from the browser I get the following json:

```
{
    "myarray":{
        "_id":"12345qwer",
        "value":"https://www.awildurl.com/q/12345678/test-1-1234-123.html",
        "provider":"foo",
        "price":null
    }
}
```

I get the data in php from the server and print with:

```
$json_content = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_decoded=json_decode($json_content, TRUE);
echo "provider: ".$json_decoded['myarray']['provider']."<br>"; //foo
```

The problem appears when I try to get and print the url (value), I get a null variable:

```
echo "value: ".$json_decoded['myarray']['value']."<br>"; //foo
```

Also when I try to print_r the array right after getting the url in php I get null in the point where the actual url should be:

```
print_r($json_decoded); //{"myarray":{"_id":"12345qwer","value":null,"provider":"foo"}}
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I get the actual url from the array cell?

Comment: What is in your output when you do `print($json_content)` ?

Comment: As the dumped value of `$json_decoded` shows: `value` is null. What makes you think that your code should behave different?

Comment: @NicoHaase Price is null, but not value. 

Like Ivan said, there has to be something wrong with the input json or it cannot be the same as what you provided, because when I do exactly the same as you I get the result without any problems:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d18be61b3c05842c6c7c83fe782340765c8ba63c

Comment: `"value":null,` - do you see something else at the end of this question? I would assume that the JSON result provided by the server is not the same